# Supabase POSTGIS SQL function to return records within given distance from user

Tags: sql, postgis, supabase-database, supabase-function

I am not familiar with SQL or PostGIS as a front end engineer, but I have to build out this backend API with Supabase.  I followed [their docs](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/database/extensions/postgis?language=js#order-by-distance) which is almost what I need, except that this will return ALL records.

I want to pass a 3rd argument `distance`:

```
create or replace function nearby_flies(lat float, long float)
returns table (pattern public.submitted_images.pattern%TYPE, dist_meters float)
language sql
as $$
  select pattern, st_distance(location, st_point(long, lat)::geography) as dist_meters
  from public.submitted_images
  order by location <-> st_point(long, lat)::geography;
$$;
```

My table is written as:

```
create table
  public.submitted_images (
    user_id uuid not null,
    created_at timestamp with time zone not null default now(),
    bucket_id text null,
    pattern text null,
    location geography (point) not null,
    constraint submitted_images_pkey primary key (created_at),
    constraint submitted_images_pattern_fkey foreign key (pattern) references pattern (label),
    constraint submitted_images_user_id_fkey foreign key (user_id) references auth.users (id)
  ) tablespace pg_default;

create index submitted_images_geo_index
  on public.submitted_images
  using GIST (location);
```

and I have confirmed that the table is recording the `POINT` record.

How would this query be re-written to take into account only records that are within `X` distance as an additional argument?

Comment: see `st_dwithin`

Answer (score 0):

As [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77424611/supabase-postgis-sql-function-to-return-records-within-given-distance-from-user#comment136508186_77424611) by [@JGH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7635569/jgh), that's exactly what [`st_dwithin()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) is for: finding things within a certain distance. [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/68Pe-GYz):

```sql
create or replace function nearby_flies(lat float, long float, dist numeric)
returns table (pattern public.submitted_images.pattern%TYPE, dist_meters float)
language sql
as $$
  select pattern, st_distance(location, st_point(long,lat)::geography) as dist_meters
  from public.submitted_images
  where st_dwithin(location,st_point(long,lat)::geography,dist)
  order by location<->st_point(long,lat)::geography;
$$;
```

Using `st_dwithin()` directly instead of measuring the distance and comparing to your desired limit, can result in a plan with an index condition added - it'll first check this range quickly at bounding box level before proceeding to apply the actual distance filter. In the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/68Pe-GYz) you can observe a way simpler and faster plan, compared to the alternative.